# KeyBoard stop working on RubyMine IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails

KeyBoard stop working on RubyMine IDE, but still can select and navigate with Mouse. It's a frequent problem. My system configuration as following:

**RubyMine  7.1.4 running on Ubuntu 14.04 and Open JDK Java 7.**

How to get ride of this issues?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keyboard input sometimes is blocked when IBus is active.

When IDEA is used on a system with IBus is installed and running keyboard input sometimes became blocked by IBus daemon. Event Dispatching Thread is active. All other events are delivered in order - i.e. it is possible to select text or call menu actions by a mouse.

Setting **IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1** seem to help. Note that the setting is for IBus, so either set it in shell's profile, or restart IBus daemon with this option exported. Run Following command on terminal to do this.

```
export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1
ibus-daemon -d -r
```

Works like a charm, even without restarting the IDE.

See [Reference](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860)